Pausing, unpausing, resetting Gazebo Garden programmatically
I know that using ROS 1 and Gazebo classic one can pause, reset, etc Gazebo using services like /gazebo/unpause_physics, /gazebo/pause_physics, etc.
I am now using ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo Garden and I can't find any services that achieve the same. Do I need to install some special plugin to achieve this? Or is it done differently now (not via services)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
